# Facebook php curl not returning response when content length is set

Tags: php, facebook, curl, header, php-curl

I am trying to virtually post form data to delete lots of posts on facebook. But neither code is giving any error nor the post is being deleted.

Whenever I set content length in header array of php curl, facebook does not respond and page keeps loading.

Can anyone point out whats the mistake in it.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fi);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
array(
'authority:mbasic.facebook.com',
'method:POST',
'path:'.$actionl,
'scheme:https',
'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate',
'accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
'cache-control:max-age=0',
'content-length:136',
'content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'origin:https://mbasic.facebook.com',
'referer:'.$reffr,
'upgrade-insecure-requests:1',
'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.4; Series60/5.0 Nokia5233/21.1.004; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/525 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 BrowserNG/7.2.5.2 3gpp-gba'
)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . '/fb.txt' ); // The cookie file'
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . '/fb.txt' );    // cookie jar
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Scraping Facebook or using any kind of automated tools to interact with their UI is not allowed.